# SQL Query - SELECT distinct IDs with 2 extra column

Tags: sql

Im working in an SQL Query like this: (sorted by the station visits)

```
TRAIN_ID   TYPE   STATION
111        'KC'   New York
111        'KC'   Washington
111        'KC'   Boston
111        'KC'   Denver
222        'FC'   London
222        'FC'   Paris
```

I'd like to SELECT distinct trains, and actual row must include the first and the last station like:

```
TRAIN_ID    TYPE     FIRSTSTATION    LASTSTATION
111         'KC'     New York        Denver
222         'FC'     Denver          Paris
```

Anyone can give a hand? Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: Database tables do not have any order upon which you can base such a query. You'd need an additional order column.

Comment: Are you using SQLServer?

Comment: is FirstStation = Denver for train 222 intentional or a typo (was expecting London)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you find something to define an order on the stations so that you can identify the "last" and "first" one, the following should work:

```
WITH numbered_stations AS (
  SELECT train_id, 
         type, 
         row_number() over (partition by train_id order by some_order_column) as rn,
         count(*) over (partition by train_id) as total_stations
  FROM the_unknown_table
)
SELECT f.train_id,  
      f.type, 
      f.station as first_station, 
      l.station as last_station
FROM (SELECT train_id, 
         type
         station
  FROM numbered_stations
  WHERE rn = 1
) f
  JOIN (SELECT train_id, 
               type, 
              station
        FROM numbered_stations 
        WHERE rn = total_stations) l 
  ON f.train_id = l.train_id
ORDER BY train_id
```

This assumes that `some_order_column` can be used to identify the last and first station.

It also assumes that the `type` is always the same for all combinations of train_id and station.

The shown syntax is standard ANSI SQL and should work on most modern DBMS.

Comment: +1 for well-explained, well-formatted query that addresses the question that should've been asked

Comment: Doesn't it only work with Oracle? He didn't mention specific DBMS.

Comment: @AlexGitelman: should work with PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Teradata, Sybase, Firebird 3.0. The CTE (`WITH ...`) is not strictly necessary and if that is replaced with a derived table it should also work with H2 and Derby (although a bit uglier)